# SignalR SSL Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, ssl, signalr

I am having a SignalR server which also connects to other SignalR servers (each server is publisher and subscriber) and normal clients also connect to these servers. First I was using normal http and everything was working fine.
Now I have switched to https genererating my own certificates and so on - that's also working fine.
When only one server is started and it doesn't have an open connection to another server I can connect with as many clients as I want, everything works fine but here is the problem now:
As soon as my server is connected to another server it refuses any connection attempt from any client.
"await _hubConnection.Start()" always throws an exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".
The same happens when I am trying to authenticate via SSLstream (I am using that for getting the certificate from the server, before I open the hub connection):
"await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(host)" works fine when my server has no connection to another server, but as soon as this is the case, the method also throws the Exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Does my SignalR server require any special settings when using https?

I am using Windows 11 on my server (which is a VM on an Windows Server machine) an my clients (second server is on Windows 10 which is also a VM on an Windows Server machine).

That's my server configuration:

```cs
if (CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<XAMComSettings>().PubSubEnabled)
{
    GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule(CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogger<ValueHub>>()));
    GlobalHost.Configuration.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize = null;

    app.Map(ValueClientConfig.VALUE_HUB_URL, map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
           .RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true });
    });
}

var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.EnableSwagger(c => { c.SingleApiVersion("1.0.0", "PubSub Diagnostics"); }).EnableSwaggerUi();
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new DiagnosticsExceptionLogger(CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<DiagnosticsExceptionLogger>()));

config.Filters.Add(new ThrottlingFilter
{
    Policy = new ThrottlePolicy
    {
        IpThrottling = true,
        ClientThrottling = true,
        EndpointThrottling = true
    },
    Repository = new MemoryCacheRepository()
});
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I tried to disable certification valdiation, but I don't think it has anything to do with my certificates.
I set SslProtocols to none so the OS can decide.
I turned off firewalls.
I already did my research, but the cases I found here or other websites were that there was no connection possible at all.
There must be a settings which I am not aware of and which a haven't found yet.

**Edit:

I found the issue:**
I was also binding the certificates to my port that I got from my server. So if one server was connecting to another it bound the certificate from the other server. I didn't know that a client just has to have the certificate and it's not required to bind it.